# Word 2010: unable to open other *.doc files

Tags: microsoft-word, upgrade

I had word 2007 and upgraded it to 2010 so it became unable to open other *.doc files against created with on 2010 version.

What is the problem here, is there any issues?

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a common issue. [Here is a possible solution](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/word/thread/ed16e1ef-6a6d-4bc9-be21-923b072018cb) that deals with multiple versions of the OS.

Suggestion 1: Change the template that is used by the document in Word 2010

====================

Step a: Determine the template that is used by the document
1.       Open the problem document in Word 2010.

2. Click File on the Ribbon, and then click Word Options.
3. Click Add-Ins.
4. In the Manage box, click Templates under View and manage Office add-ins
5. Click Go.

The Document template box will list the template that is used by the document. If the template listed is Normal, go to step 2. Otherwise, go to step 3.

Step b: Rename the global template (Normal.dotm)
Follow the steps for the operating system that you are using:

Windows Vista and Windows 7

1. Exit Word 2010
2. Click Start.
3. In the Start Search box, type the following text, and then press ENTER: 
   %userprofile%\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates
4. Right-click Normal.dotm, and then click Rename.
5. Type Oldword.old, and then press ENTER.
6. Close Windows Explorer.
7. Start Word 2010, and then open the document.

Microsoft Windows XP

1. Exit Word 2010
2. Click Start, and then click Run.
3. In the Open box, type the following text, and then press ENTER: 
   %userprofile%\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates
4. Right-click Normal.dotm, and then click Rename.
5. Type Oldword.old, and then press ENTER.
6. Close Windows Explorer.

Step c: Change the document template
1.       Open the problem document in Word 2010.

2. Click File on the Ribbon, and then click Word Options.
3. Click Add-Ins.
4. In the Manage box, click Templates under View and manage Office add-ins, and then click Go.
5. Click Attach.
6. In the Templates folder, click Normal.dotm, and then click Open.
7. Click OK to close the Templates and Add-ins dialog box.
8. Exit Word 2010

Step d: Verify that changing templates worked.
1.       Start Word 2010.

2. Click File on the Ribbon, and then click Open.
3. Click the document you want to open, and then click Open.

Can we open it by this way? If not, go to next suggestions.

Suggestion 2: Use safe mode

=============

Step 1: Start Windows in safe mode

Windows Vista and Windows 7

a.                   Remove all floppy disks, CDs, and DVDs from your computer, and then restart the computer.

b.                  Click Start , click the arrow next to Lock or Shutdown, and then click Restart.

c.                   Use one of the following procedures:

1. •If your computer has a single operating system installed, press and hold the F8 key as the computer restarts. You must press F8 before the Windows logo appears. If the Windows logo appears, you must try again by waiting until the Windows logon prompt appears, and then shutting down and restarting the computer. 
   •If your computer has more than one operating system, use the arrow keys to highlight the operating system that you want to start in safe mode, and then press F8. 
   d.                  On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to select Safe Mode, and then press ENTER.

e.                  Log on to your computer by using a user account that has administrator rights.

Windows XP

a.                   Remove all floppy disks, CDs, and DVDs from your computer, and then restart the computer.

b.                  Click Start, and then click Shut Down.

c.                   In the What do you want the computer to do list, click Restart, and then click OK.

d.                  Hold down the CTRL key as you restart the computer.

e.                  When you see the Starting Windows message, press F8, use the arrow keys to select Safe Mode on the Startup menu, and then press ENTER.

Step 2: Verify that starting in safe mode fixes the problem.

a.                   Start Word.

b.                  In Word 2007, click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Open.
In Word 2010, click File on the Ribbon, and then click Open.

c.                   Click the document you want to open, and then click Open.

Comment: What solution? Link is down. Best if you can find and quote it in your answer.

Comment: @random ..... solution added.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing. I just right clicked on the .doc file, selected "save as... and selected "Microsoft Office Word (*.docx)" from the drop-down list. To save time, you can select multiple .doc files and save each of them in this way, and then confirm all of the dialog windows afterwards!

.docx files will open from the icon. But .doc files won't, for whatever reason.

Comment: Hi Matt, did you look at the first answer, which does answer the question. Yours provides a work-around but does not address the problem. Word 2010 should open .doc files.